# Counting rows with a SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I have a problem in my code. I want to get the row count from my `SqlDataAdapter` if there are any rows.

Comment: Would it be the same effect if you check first if the SqlDataAdapter returns null value?

Comment: @eibhrum - you can have an empty data adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try `dt.Rows.Count` since that is a table and has rows.

Comment: `dt.Rows.Count` is a property not a method, so this won't compile

Comment: @brokenglass, what would i do?

Comment: yes I saw that just before your comment... seems between the two of us we might write a line that compiles.  :D

Answer (score 4):

You were doing an assignment instead of a comparison, you have to use `==` :

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0 )
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Since when does a data adapter have a rows attribute?

Comment: typo - should have been `dt` - fixed